# Rails 5 - form not updating - param is missing or the value is empty: tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails 5 app, I have a form (below) that is loading correctly, yet not updating. No notification of errors (should pass all validations (only on presence = true)).

Error

> param is missing or the value is empty: tag

pointing to the tag_params method.

All help, suggestions, improvement, simplification welcome!

[image]

**Controller**

```
def update
  tagable = detect_tagable
  @tag = tagable.tags.find(params[:id])
  @tag.update(tag_params)
  render '_tag_update'
end

def tag_params
  params.require(:tag).permit(:content, :location, :tagtype_id, annotation_attributes: { annotation_ids:[] }, document_attributes: { document_ids:[] })
end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'dashboard#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, :documenttypes, :tagtypes, :business_partners

  resources :documents do
    resources :comments, :tags
    get "pdf", on: :member 

  end

  resources :annotations do
    resources :comments, :tags
    get "pdf", on: :member

end

get "annotations/:id/annotate" => "annotations#annotate", as: 'annotate'
```

**Form**:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@tag.tagable, @tag], html: { class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true },
    wrapper: :horizontal_form,
    wrapper_mappings: {
        check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
        radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
        boolean: :horizontal_boolean
      } do |f| %>

    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.input :content, placeholder: 'Tagged content'%>

    <%= f.association :tagtype, prompt: 'Select tag type', :collection => Tagtype.active.order(:name).where(:documenttype => @tag.tagable.documenttype_id) %>

    <%= f.input :location, prompt: 'add as x1, y1, x2, y2' %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end -%>
```

**Rails server returns this** (appears to be executed)

> Started PATCH "/annotations/6/tags/46" for ::1 at 2016-10-15 16:15:09 +0200
>   Processing by TagsController#update as HTML
>     Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"7JMnYxy00zQXLIEfETSGWcMxPQFwNMYRJRyCeL9RMAQYtLygrf3UjamlZQdR/ajgTY2wH6DKOTeLE6yAUqbc6w==", "annotation_id"=>"6", "id"=>"46"}
>     User Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>     Annotation Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "annotations".* FROM "annotations" WHERE "annotations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>     Tag Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."tagable_id" = $1 AND "tags"."tagable_type" = $2 AND "tags"."id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["tagable_id", 6], ["tagable_type", "Annotation"], ["id", 46], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>      (0.2ms)  BEGIN
>     Tagtype Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "tagtypes".* FROM "tagtypes" WHERE "tagtypes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>      (0.2ms)  COMMIT
>     Rendering tags/_tag_update.html.erb within layouts/application
>     Annotation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "annotations".* FROM "annotations" WHERE "annotations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>     Tagtype Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "tagtypes".* FROM "tagtypes" WHERE "tagtypes"."active" = $1 AND "tagtypes"."documenttype_id" = 2 ORDER BY "tagtypes"."name" ASC  [["active", true]]
>     Rendered tags/_tag_update.html.erb within layouts/application (43.0ms)
>     Rendered shared/_menu.html.erb (2.9ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 220ms (Views: 203.3ms | ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)

Comment: Try to add a bang to your save to see if it runs in to any errors, i.e `@tag.save!` Also, in your update controller action shouldn't you call `update(params)` instead of `save`?

Comment: the bang make no difference; why should I make it update(params) ?

Comment: Because using save you are saving the current state of the record, what you want to do is update it with your new values from the form.

Comment: ok; agree - now with update(params) - better I think 'update(tag_params)', I get error: 'param is missing or the value is empty: tag'

Comment: Did you define tag_params in your controller? It's good practice to have a private method in your controller where you permit only the desired input. Check the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html), seems like controller structure might be your issue. (Check under the **Strong Parameters** section.

Comment: Yes I have - see updated question please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125795/discussion-between-ozgar-and-dimitri-de-ruiter).